# Unable to update to watchOS 7

Tags: ios, upgrade, software-update, apple-watch, watchos

I’m having a lot of trouble (and have spent the better part of a day) trying to upgrade to watchOS 7 (on a Series 5, with iOS 14 installed on the paired iPhone).

It takes probably an hour or so to “download to watch”, then *finally* finishes, and I get the error “unable to verify update because you weren’t connected to the internet”. Then, I have to start the entire download process over again. I’m connected to both data and a WiFi connection, and the watch is on it’s charger.

Things I’ve tried:

1. Re-pairing the watch
2. Restarting both devices
3. Updating from the watchOS settings app
4. Connecting to three different WiFi networks
5. Closing and re-opening the app
6. “Cold” restart on the phone
7. Connecting the watch to the same WiFi network, and different WiFi networks
8. Connecting the phone and watch to another phone’s WiFi hotspot
9. Connecting a laptop directly to the LAN Ethernet, and using it’s mobile hotspot
10. Charging and depleting the phone twice
11. Turning off the cellular connection, and using only WiFi

Comment: Is the error message on your iPhone? If so, can you attach your iPhone to a mac, and upload relevant log messages? (open Console, then select your phone on the side)

Comment: @JoyJin Hi! Yes, the error message is on the iPhone. Unfortunately, I do not have access to a Mac (I don’t suppose this is also possible on Windows somehow?).